# keep old content loaded previously in react pagination

Tags: reactjs

I'm new using react.

I have an array from php.

React is getting it using axios to print some posts.
I'd like to show 10 posts and when user scroll down I get more 10 posts.
It is working ok. The problem is react is overwriting my old posts from the screen, I'd to keep all posts, not only the new ones loaded... Any ideas why react is only keeping the new ones?

my return:

```
  return (
    <>
      {posts.map((post, index) => {

        if (posts.length === index + 1) {
            number = post.id;
          return <div className={classes.post} ref={lastPostElementRef} key={post.id}>{post.titulo}</div>
        }
        else {
          return <div className={classes.post} key={post.id}>{post.titulo}</div>
        }
      })}
      <div>{loading && 'Loading...'}</div>
      <div>{error && 'Error'}</div>
    </>
  )
```

my axios:

```
   axios({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'http://localhost/posts.php',
      params: { q: query, page: pageNumber },
      cancelToken: new axios.CancelToken(c => cancel = c)
    }).then(res => {
      setPosts(prevPosts => {
        return res.data
      })
      if(res.data.length < 10) {
          setHasMore(false); // total pagination items 10
      }
      else {
          setHasMore(true);
      }
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the `state` in `functional` component, `React` will replace the previous state.

When you update a state variable, unlike `this.setState` in a component class, the function returned by useState does not automatically merge update objects, it replaces them.

Solution : You have to add the old state and the new state in a new array and then set this as the new state. You could use `spread` syntax to copy the old and the new state.

**Example:**

```
axios({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'http://localhost/posts.php',
  params: { q: query, page: pageNumber },
  cancelToken: new axios.CancelToken(c => cancel = c)
}).then(res => {
  setPosts(prevPosts => {
    return [...prevPosts, ...res.data, ]
  })
  if (res.data.length < 10) {
    setHasMore(false); // total pagination items 10
  }
  else {
    setHasMore(true);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to add newly fetched results to current state;
Use this;

```
    return [...prevPosts ,...res.data]
```

instead of

```
    return res.data
```